# how to 'off' all events with one call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, api

Simply the question is that, how to off all events with one call, for example if I have another events like 'mouseleave, mouseenter, keyup, keydown ...'.

What I'm doing here is that each time the dialog is showed I turn off (`off`) the events, this '`off`' works well with `click`, but I want a code to turn off all events with one call, I tryed: `$('.dialog').off('**');` but it doesn't works. If I don't use off I get multiple calls to click (multiple hello worlds).

I have a code like this:

myform.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('.dialog').off('click');
    $('.dialog').on('click', '.mybutton', function() {
        alert('hello world');
    });
});
</script>
<input type="button" class="mybutton" value="click me!"/>
```

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
    function openDialog()
    {
        $.post( '/myform.php', null, function (data) {
            $('.dialog').html( data );
            $('.dialog').show();
        });
    }

    function closeDialog()
    {
        $('.dialog').hide();
        $('.dialog').html('');
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dialog" style="display:none">

</div>
<input type="button" onclick="openDialog();" value="show dialog!" />
<input type="button" onclick="closeDialog();" value="close dialog!" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you performing a POST with no data to return some HTML?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass no arguments and it unbinds all of them.

```
$("element").off();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N3HAr/).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the unbind() method would work here.

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

"removes all previously attached event handlers

Comment: `.unbind` is equivalent to `.off()`

Comment: then it should work with no arguement passed to remove all event handlers